# dropzone doesn't work when client and server are not the same with ajax, spring mvc and spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, dropzone.js

I have a spring mvc web application.

In a page, I have integrated a dropzone component ro upload multiple files.

I have a controller (rest) which is responsible for upload the received files in request.

When I test in my machine (localhost), everything works fine and files uploaded succesfully to the server.

But when I deploy my app on a remote server (tomcat in another machine), I can drag and drop files to dropzone div but when I clikc to send files to server, I got the following error:

dropzone.js:1386 POST 10.172.197.37:8181/vamhos/import net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

and the line 1386 in dropzone js file is:

```
 Dropzone.prototype.submitRequest = function(xhr, formData, files) {
      return xhr.send(formData);
 };
```

I can't understand what the problem is and It seems that the files aren't even trannsferred to the server...

I am blocked and I really need to fix it...

I use spring security for security purpose in my app...

the code of my controller is as the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/importData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, String env, String exportDate,
            String archivable) throws Exception {

        // get archiv checkbox value (wether csv files should be archived or
        // not)
        int isArchibvable = 0;
        if (archivable != null)
            isArchibvable = 1;
        if (isArchibvable == 1)
            LOGGER.info("Les données importées vont être archivées");

        // Getting uploaded files from the request object and save csv files
        // into file system
        Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = request.getFileMap();
        Map<String, String> csvFilesPaths = new HashMap<>();
        for (MultipartFile multipartFile : fileMap.values()) {
            if (!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
                csvFilesPaths.put(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(),
                        fileSaveService.saveFileToPath(multipartFile, envFolderName));
            }
        }

        importDataService.importData(csvFilesPaths, lastExportDate, new Long(env), 1);
        return new ModelAndView("import");
```

If anyone has an idea, it will be really great...

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,

Comment: could you post your controller code

Comment: if you are using csrf protection in you app you have to disable it.or you have to send the csrf tokens in spring security .this might be your problem

Comment: the csrf is disabled.

Comment: did you check the context path of the application .do you have same URL or different URL

Comment: What did you mean by context path of the application?

Comment: your app url http://10.172.197.37:8181/vamhos/app to something like http://10.172.197.37:8181/

Comment: For my local server url is: localhost:8080, For the remote server url is: 10.172.197.37:8181/vamhos

Comment: change your form url  add /vamhos  to your url and try .

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping